# Transformation of inverse to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have $X = (U'WU)^{-1}U'$ to be solved. Suppose $U'$ is $3 \times 7, W$ is $7 \times 7$ positive definite matrix, $U'$ is of rank 3.

So, I transformed $(U'WU)^{-1}U'$ as

$(U'WU)^{-1}U'WU = I\\
XWU = I\\
U'WX' = I\\
(I \otimes U'W) vec(X') = vec(I).\\
$

When I solved $ X = (U'WU)^{-1}U'$ and as the above linear system using R, the answers are slightly different. Can anyone just point out whether there is something wrong with the above logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) A standard and the simplest way (if there's nothing better to do) to compute $X$ is first to compute the Cholesky factorization of the SPD matrix $U'WU=LL'$ and then solve the system with multiple right-hand sides $LL'X=U'$. Note that $U'WU$ is $3\times 3$ so this approach is very cheap.

2) With the approach in question, the problem is already in finding $X$ from $XWU=I$, which is not uniquely solvable [any $3\times 7$ matrix $Y$ whose rows are orthogonal to the columns of $WU$ will also satisfy $(X+Y)WU=I$].

Comment: How do you get $LL'X =WU$? Actually, the dimensions of the matrices are so huge. I want to find away of getting rid of the inverse matrix.

Comment: It should of course be LL'X=U'. You also do not need to compute the inverse but to solve a sequence of (independent) square linear systems back forward/backward substitution.